# React JS. remove function from button after button is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to unmount. Return does not work. I need to be able to press button and after function completes then the function will be remove from the button

```
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    ipcRenderer.send(
      "EDITOR",
      [ type, typeValue],
      "editor_response"
    );
    onClose(selectedValue);
  };

  return <div>
    <Button onClick={handleSubmit} color="primary">
      Ok
    </Button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Add `hasBeenClicked: false` to the state, update it to `true` after the first click and check its value on the next clicks to exit the function.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the cleanest solution is a state variable that determines whether the handler should be active or not.

```js
const MyComp = () => {

  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false;

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setPressed(true);
    ipcRenderer.send(
      "EDITOR",
      [ type, typeValue],
      "editor_response"
    );
    onClose(selectedValue);
  };

  const noop = () => {};
  
  return <div>
    <Button onClick={!pressed ? handleSubmit : noop} color="primary">
      Ok
    </Button>
  </div>;
};
```